# is this method correct to call a method from other class?

Tags: python, class, oop

I am new to python oops.Is this method is correct to call method of other class. Code shown below

```
class Example():
    def function(self):
        print("foo")
class Example2():
    def function2:
        Example.function(Example)
```

Comment: *What are you trying to achieve here*?

Comment: You need to provide a more real-word example, otherwise this is pretty hard to answer. Your example works, but it also doesn't make really much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not, because the function as you defined it is an instance method. The correct way in this case would be:

```
class Example2():
    Example().function()
```

Or this (which is less readable)

```
class Example2():
    Example.function(Example())
```

Another alternative, since `self` is never used in `function`, is to just define it as a static method or a class method:

```
class Example():
    @staticmethod
    def function():
        print("foo")
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
class Example2():
    Example.function()
```

Note: all of this only runs during the definition of `Example2` since it is not inside of any function of `Example2`